# No data loading on the inbox, achievements and review boxes in the promotion site

Tags: bug, top-bar, promotions

In the Promotion site https://contests.stackoverflow.com, when we are clicking on the inbox, achievements and review icons from the top bar, only the place holder is visible and there is no data loading on that.

> [image: Promotion site]

Receiving the 404 error for the `Request URL:https://contests.stackoverflow.com/content/img/progress-dots.gif` in the browser's network tab.

Comment: Looks like they  copied the HTML but forgot to copy the JS. :/