# Review option lists Inbox messages in Promotion page top bar

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar, promotions

There is a bug reported about the [Promotion page top bar loading issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341301/312043). Currently all the top bar menu options are loading with the data, but there is an issue with that.

While clicking on the Review menu, instead of the review queue items the inbox message details are repeated.
Whether the "Review" button can be removed or clicking on the "Review" button will list the Stack Overflow queue items?

GIF for reference:

[image: Review issue]

Comment: You mention here that "the top bar menu options are loading with the data" - does that mean you're no longer experiencing the bug you previously reported? Because it seems to still be happening, for me. (Since none of the dropdowns are appearing for me there, obviously I can't reproduce the bug in this post, but I am able to reproduce that other bug.)

Comment: ...Actually the dropdowns aren't opening for me at all on contests.stackoverflow.com, which I now realize isn't the same issue you reported previously.